# Node.js soap.createClientAsync() and wsdl as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

How to create a soap client in Node.js using the npm soap package if I have the wsdl as a string?

```
const soap = require('soap')
const wsdl = '<definitions> ... </definitions>'

const client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdl) // Wrong: soap thinks that wsdl is a filename
```

P.S. save the wsdl string into a file is not an option

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have to add an XML header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`).

```
const soap = require('soap')

const wsdl = '<definitions> ... </definitions>'
const xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>${wsdl}`
const client = await soap.createClientAsync(xml)
```